# FormArray returning as FormControl instead of FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm having trouble with nested FormArrays in Angular reactive forms. One of my form arrays correctly returns as a FormArray and the other returns as FormControl. In the initialMaterials() function I have two console.logs. `console.log(control)` returns a FormControl item and `console.log(this.objectServiceJobsArray)` returns a FormArray.

I need to be able to add materials to specific jobs in the array and change them in the form when necessary.

```
this.objectServiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          onHolidays: [this.objectService.onHolidays],
          objectServiceJobs: this.formBuilder.array([this.objectServiceJobs()]),
          isBillable: [this.objectService.isBillable],
          defaultPrice: [this.objectService.defaultPrice],
          pricePerHour: [this.objectService.pricePerHour],
          doneWeekly: [this.doneWeekly],
        });

objectServiceJobs(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      job: [''],
      workDetail: [''],
      competentWorkers: [[]],
      materials: this.formBuilder.array([this.objectServiceJobMaterials()])
    });
}

objectServiceJobMaterials(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      material: [null],
      quantity: [null]
    });
}

initialMaterials(job) {
    const index = (<FormArray>this.objectServiceForm.get('objectServiceJobs')).controls.findIndex(x => x.value.job.id === job.id);
    const control = (<FormArray>this.objectServiceForm.controls['objectServiceJobs']).at(index).get('materials') as FormArray;
    console.log(control);
    console.log(this.objectServiceJobsArray);

    // job.materials.forEach(mat => {
    //   this.objectServiceJobsArray[index].materials.push(this.makeMaterialFormGroup(mat));
    // });
}
```

Comment: I have created a stackblitz example and your code is working fine(with a small change) . Refer : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hp7hb6

Comment: for some reason its still returning as FormControl for me and gives the"materials.push is not a funciton" error

Comment: @CruelEngine console.log(objectServiceJobs.at(index)) also shows materials as FormControl under controls :(

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz and it is working fine as ``console.log(objectServiceJobs.at(index))`` is returning me a ``FormGroup``

Comment: @CruelEngine Yes, in your example everything is working as it should but for me it still returns FormControl for some reason.

Comment: objectServiceForm.objectServiceJobs.materials are NOT a formArray, I supouse you want make some like `this.objectServiceJobs.at(index).push(this.formBuilder.group({material:mat,quantity:''})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code in my IDE but changed the style of extracting controls and I can see that console.log(control) returns me as FormArray.

```
initialMaterials(job) {
    const objectServiceJobs = this.objectServiceForm.get('objectServiceJobs') as FormArray;
    const index = objectServiceJobs.controls.findIndex(x => x.value.job.id === job.id);
    const control = objectServiceJobs.at(index).get('materials') as FormArray;
    console.log(control);
  }
```

Comment: Ugh I'm still getting FormControl even though I can see in @CruelEngine s StackBlitz that it should return a FormArray :/

Answer (score 1):

As saloo said the code works perfectly and returns a FormArray, just keep in mind that job is a form control (value isn't an object) so `x.value.job.id` is always undefined inside this line :

```
const index = objectServiceJobs.controls.findIndex(x => x.value.job.id === job.id);
```

Comment: I dont know, it seems to get the index correctly though

Comment: it's just because both variables are undefined so equality will be found always at index 0