# Why does a formArray turn into a formControl in angular for a reactive form when looped more than once? How do I stop it or force return of formArray?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

**Background**

The data is two arrays of objects inside an array of objects inside another array of objects and cannot be changed. This data is collected via a reactive form and each array can have unknown length. I want to not only collect the information via the form but show what's already entered and allow the user to edit it via the form.

Confirmed this happens in Angular8 My project and Angular9 the stackBlitz.

**The Problem**

*Expected*

When I select the `formArray` to load existing data into I expect it to return a `formArray` every iteration so I can use array functions like .push to iterate over existing data and load it into the form to show the user.

*Actual*

The first instance returns a `formArray`, any time after that it returns as a `formControl` and unable to use array functions to manipulate the data to show.

**Code**

I am using a component within another so showing all the applicable code would probably be very long. I've included a stackBlitz, which logs what happens when I try and select the `formArray` in question.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-array-issue

*Some code that will help context right away.*

Data setup (seen in: stepper-form-component.ts starting line 112 with data)

```js
   item_types: [
        {
          group: string,
          is_active: boolean,
          item_fees: [
            {
              fee: string,
              description: string
            },
          ],
          item_options_settings: [
            {
              option_name: string,
              option_for: string
              },
          ]
        },
      ],
      classifications: [
        {
          name: string
        },
      ]
    };
```

form setup (seen in: stepper-form-component.ts starting line 46)

```js
  buildForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      item_types: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          group: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
          is_active: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
          item_fees: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.group({
              fee: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
              description: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
            })
          ]),
          item_options_settings: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.group({
              option_name: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
              option_for: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
            })
          ])
        })
      ]),
      classifications: this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.getData();
  }
```

selecting the array and trying to load data to it (seen in: item-specific-settings starting line 65)

```js
  loadData() {
    // REVIEW: for some reason both fees and options the first is formarray the following are formcontrols
    console.log(
      `...control.item_fees for index of ${this.index}`,
      this.itemSpecificSettingFormGroup.controls[this.index].controls.item_fees
    );
    const feesArray = this.itemSpecificSettingFormGroup.controls[this.index]
      .controls.item_fees as FormArray;
    this.item.item_fees.forEach(fee => {
      const newGroup = this.fb.group({
        fee: [fee.fee, [Validators.required]],
        description: [fee.description, [Validators.required]]
      });
      feesArray.insert(feesArray.length, newGroup);
    });

    const optionsArray = this.itemSpecificSettingFormGroup.controls[this.index]
      .controls.item_options_settings as FormArray;
    this.item.item_options_settings.forEach(option => {
      const newGroup = this.fb.group({
        option_name: [option.option_name, [Validators.required]],
        option_for: [option.option_for, [Validators.required]]
      });
      optionsArray.insert(optionsArray.length, newGroup);
    });
  }
```

**I've tried**

I did first look at this similar question [formarray-returning-as-formcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639872/formarray-returning-as-formcontrol-instead-of-formarray)

- For the first answer using `this.itemSpecificSettingFormGroup.controls[this.index].get('item_fees')` still results in `formArray` first iteration and `formControl` every time after.
- For the second answer I already know the ID it doesn't apply.

I've also been directed to [Chrome 80 introduces angular breaking bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/f1wzaj/psa_chrome_80_introduces_angular_breaking_bug/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share)

- But my situation doesn't occur at same cadence that others endure: the error first then fine after or random through out. My issue happens after the first iteration and still exists in Firefox, which to the best of my knowledge is not chromium related.

**Questions**

1) Why is this happening, why would the first result be a formArray and the following be formControls?

2) How do I make it recognize a formArray to show the right data?